# Javascript codes working with radio button and addlistener and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I have some codes to test a function with array knowledge, which will display "I am Tom, and I am 25" when I select "1st person" button, etc.

But sadly my codes do not work.

Pls help me out.

Here is my script:

```
    names = ["Tom", "Jack", "John"];
    ages = ["25", "30", "18"];
    function introduce(names, ages) {
        outputDiv = document.getElementById(output);
        outputDiv.value = "I am " + names + "," + "and I am " + ages;
    }

    if (document.querySelector('input[name="radio_btn"]')) {
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio_btn"]').forEach((elem) => {
            elem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
                introduce(names, ages);
            });
        });
    }
```

And my Html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-danger text-white">
        <strong>Introduce</strong>
        <div class="">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" />1st person
            　<input type="radio" name="radio_btn" />2nd person
            　<input type="radio" name="radio_btn" />3rd person

            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- <label for="output_combo">Output</label> -->
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="outputCombo" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the name and age to `introduce()` function, not the array if you want to see individual person information. Also the output query selector should have the proper id to select.

```js
output = 'outputCombo'
names = ["Tom", "Jack", "John"];
ages = ["25", "30", "18"];

function introduce(name, age) {
    outputDiv = document.getElementById(output);
    outputDiv.value = "I am " + name + "," + "and I am " + age;
}

if (document.querySelector('input[name="radio_btn"]')) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio_btn"]').forEach((elem, i) => {
        elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
            introduce(names[i], ages[i]);
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg-danger text-white">
        <strong>Introduce</strong>
        <div class="">
            <label for="radio1">
                <input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio1"/>1st person
            </label>
            <label for="radio2">
                　<input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio2"/>2nd person
            </label>
            <label for="radio3">
                　<input type="radio" name="radio_btn" id="radio3"/>3rd person
            </label>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- <label for="output_combo">Output</label> -->
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="outputCombo" rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I modify this codes so that it will also work if I click on the label for the input button (I added the label inside the radio button). Thank you.

Comment: Please see the updated code. You need to put the radio input inside the label and use `for` and `id` to combine the label and the radio input